# How to preserve capacity of vector elements on vector::clear()?

Tags: c++, vector

When I clear a `vector<string>`, the `vector`'s capacity is preserved, but the capacities of the individual `string`s in the vector are not preserved. Is there a way to achieve this?

I can't think of a way to achieve this in a straightforward, simple manner. Here is some test code which demonstrates what I'm trying to do:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    istringstream input;
    input.str(
R"(2
This is the first sentence.
And this is the second sentence.
3
Short text.
Another short text.
The end!
)");

    vector<string> lines;

    string line; // The capacity of this string is preserved throughout.
    while (getline(input, line))
    {
        int count = stoi(line);

        lines.clear(); // This clears capacity of the string elements too!
        for (int i = 0; i < count; ++i)
        {
            getline(input, line);
            lines.push_back(line);
        }

        // process/print 'lines' here.
    }

    return 0;
}
```

One way to preserve the capacities of the `string` elements would be to never clear the `vector`, and track the size of the `vector` manually. But that wouldn't be clean at all. Is there a clean solution to this problem?

**Edit:**

If I rearrange the code the following way, I'm able to preserve the capacities of the strings in the vector. However, this is very ugly. I'm looking for a clean solution.

```
    ...
    vector<string> lines;

    string line; // The capacity of this string is preserved throughout.
    while (getline(input, line))
    {
        int count = stoi(line);

        for (int i = 0; i < count; ++i)
        {
            if (i < lines.size())
            {
                getline(input, lines[i]);
            }
            else
            {
                lines.emplace_back();
                getline(input, lines.back());
            }
        }

        // process/print 'lines' here.
        // Size is 'count'.
    }
    ...
```

Comment: Why does this matter to you ?

Comment: When you clear a vector, there are no strings in the vector, so it makes no sense to speak of the capacity of the individual strings that don't exist being retained.

Comment: If you want the vector to be cleared in each loop then declare the vector in the while loop. And as a side note you can use `push_back(std::move(line))`.

Comment: @Eljay: Yes, it makes sense. On `vector::clear()`, it would call the destructors of all the `string` elements, which would "shrink" the strings to `0` capacity. However, I'm asking if there is a way to achieve what I'm trying to accomplish - clear the `vector` but keep the capacities of individual `string` objects (somehow).

Comment: @SidS: This matters to me because I wish to prevent unnecessary re-allocations.

Comment: It sounds like you’d need to write your own implementation. To track both.

Comment: That's not what the destructors of string does, which is why it does not make sense.  What you could do is manage your own buffer and use string_view to look into the backing store of the buffer.

Comment: `line.reserve(largest_string_size);` then track the largest string.

Comment: You cannot preserve something that no longer exists. `clear()` removes all values in the vector. Those strings no longer exists. They are no more. They cease to be. They've gone to meet their maker. They are pining for the fjords. They are ex-strings. They no longer exists, and thusly have no means to preserve anything.

Comment: To make this "nice" I think you are going to have to encapsulate your current solution in a new `class` to hide the ugly.

Answer (score 0):

> How to preserve capacity of vector elements on vector::clear()?
>
> I can't think of a way to achieve this in a straightforward, simple manner.

That's because there isn't a straightforward way to achieve what you want. Once you destroy a string, its allocations are gone and there is no guaranteed way to get it back.

What you could do, is move the strings onto another vector prior to clearing the source vector. Then after clearing, you can move the strings back at your leisure. However while this technically would fulfill the requirement stated in the title, I don't see how that could be more useful to you than not clearing the vector in the first place.

---

I presume that you want to "preserve capacity" to avoid unnecessary allocation for the purpose of optimisation. Depending on what "processing" of the line means, it might be more efficient to not store them in a vector at all, but instead read the input until newline, process/print, then read the next line and so on. That way you only allocate a single string once (or a few times as the line grows up to the longest input line).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. Unfortunately I can't process a single line at a time. The processing depends on the context of all the lines in a group.

Comment: @FrancisXavier then how about a single string for the entire input, and then possibly a vector of pointers to beginning of each line?

Comment: Thanks @eeroika. Yes, that's what I ended up doing. I have the entire file in a single string and I'm using string_view to point into that. I'm not sure if I might need to modify the content yet, though.